# how to make poly render flat?

Tags: rendering

[image]

triangles are showing but I don't have an edge connecting the vertices, I just want the poly to render as flat but it renders as 2 angled triangles. Also when i connect the vertices the opposite way it still creates an extrusion shown in render. I cant really think of anything besides maybe shading smooth but I don't think I should have to.

Comment: The issue is that though the mesh is a quad, it is non-planar. That shape could not exist in real life, so the shading is showing artifacts. Almost counter-intuitively, adding an edge and shading smooth might actually solve the issue.

Comment: thank you, it looks much better!

Answer (score 1):

Christopher Bennett has given you a solution but if you want to keep a low-poly look for your object, you could give it *Auto Smooth* (*Properties* panel > *Object Data > Normals*).

When used with *Shade Flat*, *Auto Smooth* won't try to smooth between faces but only between the triangles within a face:

[image]